# Poisson XGB with sampling weights has negative values in leaves

Tags: python, statistics, xgboost, poisson

I am modelling rates (#claims/exposure) and using 'count:poisson' as objective and fitting the model using weights.

```
xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators = 500, 
                              objective='count:poisson',
                              max_depth = 3,
                              learning_rate = 0.1)

xgb_model.fit(x,y, sample_weight = w)
```

Predicted values look fine, what I don't understand are the negative values in the leaves. Taking a few boosters (trees), this is what I see:

```
xgb_model.get_booster().dump_model("./data/out.txt", with_stats=True)

# read the contents of the file
with open('./data/out.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt_model = f.read()
print(txt_model)
```

Why are the leaf values negative? How should I interpret those?

```
booster[0]:
0:[bm<7.5] yes=1,no=2,missing=1,gain=515.691406,cover=164353.438
    1:[bm<2.5] yes=3,no=4,missing=3,gain=90.7089844,cover=133852.125
        3:[ageph<52.5] yes=7,no=8,missing=7,gain=23.5478516,cover=98817.8672
            7:leaf=-0.0368952677,cover=56414.2734
            8:leaf=-0.0400237665,cover=42403.5898
        4:[coverage<1.5] yes=9,no=10,missing=9,gain=4.99926758,cover=35034.2617
            9:leaf=-0.0337322988,cover=14677.2363
            10:leaf=-0.0312859491,cover=20357.0254
    2:[ageph<20.5] yes=5,no=6,missing=5,gain=128.277222,cover=30501.3047
        5:[fuel<0.5] yes=11,no=12,missing=11,gain=151.391754,cover=519.548218
            11:leaf=0.0700000003,cover=105.722015
            12:leaf=-0.00737635046,cover=413.826172
        6:[bm<10.5] yes=13,no=14,missing=13,gain=69.1824951,cover=29981.7578
            13:leaf=-0.0272287875,cover=17357.541
            14:leaf=-0.0174960829,cover=12624.2158
booster[1]:
0:[bm<6.5] yes=1,no=2,missing=1,gain=512.917969,cover=158851.859
    1:[bm<2.5] yes=3,no=4,missing=3,gain=69.4316406,cover=123897.227
        3:[ageph<56.5] yes=7,no=8,missing=7,gain=23.9941406,cover=95110.7422
            7:leaf=-0.0366270989,cover=61948.2188
            8:leaf=-0.0399697423,cover=33162.5195
        4:[power<37.5] yes=9,no=10,missing=9,gain=5.20703125,cover=28786.4883
            9:leaf=-0.0349876434,cover=3148.77246
            10:leaf=-0.0316838399,cover=25637.7148
    2:[ageph<20.5] yes=5,no=6,missing=5,gain=128.203491,cover=34954.6328
        5:[fuel<0.5] yes=11,no=12,missing=11,gain=143.65361,cover=524.172607
            11:leaf=0.0700000003,cover=113.387726
            12:leaf=-0.00706406776,cover=410.784851
        6:[bm<10.5] yes=13,no=14,missing=13,gain=84.1767578,cover=34430.4609
            13:leaf=-0.0272307228,cover=22025.1992
            14:leaf=-0.0169284586,cover=12405.2617
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when a non-normal target is modelled, the raw predictions created by summing the leaf values of the trees will not be on the same scale as the response. E.g. for binary classification the raw predictions would be logits and for **poisson**, gamma or tweedie outcomes the raw predictions are (often) on a log scale.
So specifically for the poisson case predictions for the target are computed by
`exp(raw predictions on log scale)`.
Hence,  leaf values can be negative, but predicted counts/frequencies will always be positive.

I have created a (not too short) toy example to show how leaf values and predictions relate in the poisson case:

```py
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
import numpy as np

# generate random data
rng = np.random.default_rng(1)
n = 200
x = rng.choice([1, 2], size=n, replace=True)  # single feature either 1 or 2
r = 0.1 * x - 0.03  # poisson rate is given by x
y = rng.poisson(r)  # draw target from poisson(r) dist

# fit model
model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=2,
                     objective='count:poisson',
                     max_depth=1,
                     base_score=0.5)  # the default, just being explicit here

model.fit(x.reshape(-1, 1), y)

# look at predictions
x_test = np.array([1, 2])

# predictions on target scale
model.predict(x_test)  # array([0.3873337 , 0.41683382], dtype=float32)

# raw predictions on log scale
model.predict(x_test, output_margin=True)  # array([-0.9484687 , -0.87506765], dtype=float32)

# predictions on target scale from raw predictions
np.exp(model.predict(x_test, output_margin=True))  # array([0.38733372, 0.41683382], dtype=float32)

# look at leaf values
model.get_booster().dump_model("out.txt", with_stats=True)

with open('out.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt_model = f.read()
print(txt_model)

# booster[0]:
# 0:[f0<1.5] yes=1,no=2,missing=1,gain=0.569013596,cover=201.375275
#   1:leaf=-0.129018888,cover=96.6601257
#   2:leaf=-0.0936478898,cover=104.715141
# booster[1]:
# 0:[f0<1.5] yes=1,no=2,missing=1,gain=0.604038239,cover=180.314087
#   1:leaf=-0.12630257,cover=84.9601288
#   2:leaf=-0.0882725865,cover=95.3539505

# prediction for booster[0] - log(base_score) = booster[0] leaves
model.predict(x_test, iteration_range=(0, 1), output_margin=True) - np.log(0.5)
# array([-0.1290189, -0.0936479], dtype=float32)

# prediction for booster[1] - log(base_score) = booster[1] leaves
model.predict(x_test, iteration_range=(1, 2), output_margin=True) - np.log(0.5)
# array([-0.1263026 , -0.08827257], dtype=float32)
```